# How to change label color for line charts.js?

Tags: charts, chart.js

I try to chanage a color of line lables:

[exmaple of label pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nDhk.png)

The line has settings:

```
 const linedataset = {
      type: 'line',
      label: 'label',
      data: xavarage,
      order: 1,
      borderColor: 'rgb(225, 54, 54)',
      backgroundColor: lineBackground,
    };
```

And common settings are:

```
const chartoptions = {
      hoverBackgroundColor,
      backgroundColor,
      responsive: true,
      scales: {
        x: {},
        y: {
          min: 0,
        },
      },
      plugins: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: this.selectedCategory?.full,
          font: {
            size: 20,
          },
        },
        datalabels: {
          anchor: 'end',
          align: 'end',
        },
      },
    };
```

I have tried to usse the following code:

```
options: {
   legend: {
     color: "#ccc"
   }
}
```

But it does not work too. How to set color of label text (line graphic)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your chart uses [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/). Therefore, you need to define `color` inside `datalabels` as follows:

```
datalabels: {
  color: '#ccc',
  anchor: 'end',
  align: 'end'
},
```

Comment: Where to place `datalabels`?

Comment: What if I need different color for line. Now graphic contains [bar, line]

Comment: 'datalabels' is already present in your code, just add 'color' inside it.